# For-loop in function only loops once

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following loop inside the `getNew()` function only loops once and returns `19800` which is correct, if month equals `1`. I want to keep `getNew()` looping. Say if month equals `3` it will print: `19800, 197195.80, 195787.39`.

```js
arr1 = [200000, 0.003, 2000];

function getNew (month) {
    for (i = 0; i <= month; i ++){
        monthlyInterest = arr1[0] * arr1[1]
        paymenttoPrinciple = arr1[2] - monthlyInterest;
        newMortgageBalance = arr1[0] - paymenttoPrinciple;
        arr1[0] = newMortgageBalance;  

        return (newMortgageBalance);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `return` inside the `for` loop. This will return the first instance and break out of the function. Also if `month = 3` you wil have to change `i <= month` to `i < month`.

To fix your issue you should make another array and push the results to it.

e.g.

```js
arr1 = [200000, 0.003, 2000];

console.log(getNew(3));

function getNew(month) {
  let result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < month; i++) {
    monthlyInterest = arr1[0] * arr1[1]
    paymenttoPrinciple = arr1[2] - monthlyInterest;
    newMortgageBalance = arr1[0] - paymenttoPrinciple;
    arr1[0] = newMortgageBalance;
    result.push(newMortgageBalance);
  }

  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

`getNew(3)` returns `[19800, 197195.80, 195787.39]`.

Comment: Converted to a runnable scriptlet.